# Clay strip brush not working- won't add or subtract

Tags: sculpting

I am pretty new to Blender and just installed 3.3. I used an older version in the past and successfully used clay strips on that one. However, all brushes except my clay strip brush work in 3.3. It will not add or subtract. I have tried every setting and suggestion that I could find in the forums but nothing has worked so far. It looks as though the brush is trying to draw, but nothing happens. I've adjusted nearly every setting in the brush settings but it hasn't changed anything. I tried dyntopo too but it just destroys the model. I'm not quite sure of how to proceed to get the brush to work again, hopefully it's just a simple setting I'm missing!

Added a screenshot of my settings. I did confirm that it seems to be only happening to this project, a new file did not replicate this issue.

[image]

Comment: Any screenshot or could you please leave the blend file, so we can check?

Comment: I added a screenshot, please let me know if you need additional screenshots of settings. I wasn't sure of the ones you would need so I started with the brush settings.

Comment: Did you check that is there any texture applied it?

Comment: There's no texture on it as far as I can tell. Here is a link to a copy of the file I was using, this might be better to see it https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a6rx933GmgjB77S48YehlY9Ph4julscd/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was sure that there is texture inside that brush. Just remove it and you are done.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That solved it! Thank you so much!! I thought the black box meant there was nothing but now I realized it's the checkered board that means that.

Answer (score 0):

I note you mentioned:

'I did confirm that it seems to be only happening to this project, a new file did not replicate this issue.'

In that case, you can do the following:

- Save your current file (with the model you are working on and the broken clay strips brush).
- Open a new blender project.
- Go to File > Append in the Menus
- Browse to and select the .blend file containing the model you are working on.
- Select the Object folder, then select your model.

You can now continue to work on your model, with access to all of the default brushes.

Comment: Thank you so much for that, that is very useful to know!

Comment: Don't mention it. Would you mind accepting my answer? Thanks :)

Comment: Actually I just realised someone gave you a better answer, so maybe accept that :)